# Extending functionality through interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, architecture, interface, nullreferenceexception

I have implemented an interface `IService` that inherits functionality from a series of other interfaces and serves as a common ground for many different services.

Each of these services is being described by an interface, for example:

```
public interface IServiceOne : IService 
{
  //...
}

public class ServiceOne : IServiceOne
{
  //...
}
```

Everything up to that point works as expected:

```
IServiceOne serviceOne = new ServiceOne();
IServiceTwo serviceTwo = new ServiceTwo();
```

What I have to do now is to add a big list of constants (public variables) to each of these services which will  however be different as per service type (for example, `IServiceOne` will have different constants than `IServiceTwo`, there will be constants in `IServiceOne` that will not exist in `IServiceTwo`, etc).

What I'm trying to achieve is something like that:

```
IServiceOne serviceOne = new ServiceOne();
var someConstantValue = serviceOne.Const.SomeConstant;
```

Just because the variables will differ as of service type I decided to implement an extra interface for each of them:

```
public interface IServiceOneConstants
{
   //...
}
```

and then broaden my `IService` definition:

```
public interface IServiceOne : IService, IServiceOneConstants 
{
  //...
}

public class ServiceOne : IServiceOne
{
  //...
}
```

The problem I have now is that I don't know how to implement the concrete class for `IServiceOneConstants`. Obviously by the time one of its variables (we called them constants here) will be called it has to be instantiated, so initially I though of a `static` class but then you cannot expose a `static` class's functionality through an interface. I then tried to do it with a `singleton` and expose its `instance` via a public non-static wrapper:

```
public class Singleton : IServiceOneConstants
{
    private static Singleton _instance;

    private Singleton()
    {
        SomeConstant = "Some value";
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public String SomeConstant { get; set; }

    public Singleton Const
    {
        get
        {
            return Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I then adjusted the `IServiceOneConstants` like that:

```
public interface IServiceOneConstants
{
   Singleton Const { get; }
}
```

but when I call this:

```
IServiceOne serviceOne = new ServiceOne();
var someConstantValue = serviceOne.Const.SomeConstant;
```

I get a `null reference` exception, as `.Const` is null.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you trying to pull constants from a concrete impl using an interface type?

Comment: @cottsak I can only invoke the concrete implementation as its super-interface type because I need the functionality of the interfaces this super-interfaces derives from and on top of that I need to add some extra functionality to this super-interface that is different as per the underlying type of each concrete type.

Comment: Using abstract classes instead of interfaces may be more appropriate here.

Comment: @ŞafakGür abstract classes are still classes and as such they don't support multiple inheritance in C#, unlike C++, Java, etc, so I guess it's not really an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really helped yourself to get confused as possible, by naming different stuff same name ;)

So, first...
what you're trying to do is to access singleton instance through instance property:

```
public Singleton Const
    {
        get
        {
            return Instance;
        }
    }
```

then you are using it like:

```
serviceOne.Const
```

but that variable was never assigned. In order to assign it, you should make an instance of Singleton class, assign it to serviceOne.Const property and then you might use it.

What you need is probably something like this:

```
public class ServiceOne : IServiceOne
{
   public Singleton Const
   { 
      get
      {
         return Singleton.Instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I had to enclose the singleton inside a wrapping class for this to work but hell, it worked! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the singleton has been instantiated in `ServiceOne.Const.SomeConstant`s` getter.  If it's not, you need to instantiate it.  Then return the value of the constant.

Comment: In which specific part of the code do I have to instantiate it? This is one of the things I don't seem to get :(